# How to add javascript to handlebars template file?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

Attempted solution:

```
<body>
<h1>Attempted solution</h1>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="gamecanvas.js"></script>
</body>
```

Working but I don't want to have to code in the .hbs file if I can avoid it:

```
<body>
<h1>Working solution</h1>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 75, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
ctx.stroke();</script>
</body>
```

The only difference is I moved everything from gamecanvas.js into the script tags. What is the right way to run javascript inside handlebars? It seems referencing the script the same way I would in plain html doesn't work.

(This is a contrived short example, my actual gamecanvas.js is bigger)

Edit: Noticed in the frontend browser console, it's saying this:
`GET http://localhost:3000/gamecanvas.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Maybe double check your file directory? such as, gamecanvas.js is in the same path of your html file

Comment: It's definitely right, and the IDE autocorrects. Has something to do with it's trying to find it at localhost I think?

Comment: Figured it out!! I needed to move it into my public folder. Not sure why. Can anyone explain that? (I figured it out by seeing that there was a public/css folder and that something else doing src="..." was setting its path to public/css

Comment: You should create another question and list your folder structure to ask this question.

Comment: I think it has something to do with I'm using express

Comment: Ah! I have to do `app.use(express.static(path))`